# How to avoid Credit Card information being "saved" anywhere in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, payment

I've read some good information (on SO) about how you must avoid storing credit card information on your website.
My Rails app would be the one getting the CC information from a  on my website, correct? (as opposed to a payment processor site, if that's possible?) If so, then how do I know what all logs to "silence" so that they don't store the info?
What places (like Apache logs, my app's logs etc.) do I need to look at to remove such sensitive information ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for rails apps is just

```
filter_parameter_logging :name_of_input
```

simple usage:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    filter_parameter_logging :cc
end
```

html:

```
<input type="text" name="cc">
```

check: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/filter_parameter_logging/class

Comment: Yes, I found out about the filters for RoR, but what about filtering out data in a web server like Apache (does Apache store form info in it's log files?)